# Is there a way to change papersize in beamer?

Tags: beamer, paper-size

From what I have gathered on the interwebs, I found that beamer gives no basic options to change the papersize. I am however in desperate need of exactly that. Mind that I don't want to re-scale one or more frames to an A4, I want to actually change the size of every frame.

Is there any way to work around this?

**edit:**

*@JosephWright* The reason I need to change the paper size is because I need to end up with the different slides in PNG format. These png's have to be a certain size. I was planning on simply converting the pdf to png's like you could normally do with LaTeX, untill I found out the problem with resizing in beamer.

*@ prettygully* I have already looked at the `beamerposter` package, but it seems like  beamerposter puts all the frames on one page, what would make the conversion to PNG's impossible

**edit2:**

*@ Andrew Stacey* Your answers solved my personal problem as I was unaware of aspect ratio and my own ratio happens to be incredibly close to 16/9. I will correct the dimensions during PNG conversion.

I am still interested if anyone can come up with a general answer to the question thought.

Comment: `beamer` reduces the size of the "paper" in order to increase the effective font size. It is actually assumed that the PDF is zoomed to fullscreen or to the full paper size. To zoom it yourself check `pgfpages` (not to be confused with `pdfpages`, even if this might also be a way)

Comment: you can change the aspect ratio; otherwise have a look at the `beamerposter` package

Comment: It might be handy to know why you need to change the paper size in this way.

Comment: For the aspect ratio, see section 8.3 in the manual.

Comment: Regarding the edits: PDFs are *scalable* so can be converted to PNGs at any size without loss of detail.  The conversion program should have options for specifying the resolution (sometimes called dpi).  So you don't need to change the paper size for that (though you may want another aspect ratio).

Comment: `beamer` loads the package `geometry` So you can change the paper size with `\geometry{paper=a4}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The class `beamer` uses the package `geometry` to setup the page dimension. The package `geometry` provides the command `\geometry` to set options in the preamble. So you can simple use:

```
\geometry{paper=a4}
```

Comment: \geometry{paper=a4paper}

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of work with changing the paper size of Beamer presentations, I decided to post here and make my solution available to others.

The underlying problem is as follows: Beamer uses a standard paper size of 128x96mm, as that is more or less optimal for digital presentations. However, EDAS and other digital conference tools often check pdf files before a document upload for their paper size and they only permit certain standard formats. As of right now, they have no supported option for this - I have contacted their support and they do not seem eager to change this any time soon.

So to "rescale" an entire (already compiled) presentation you could do the following:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\geometry{papersize={11in,8.5in}}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
\begin{document}
  \includepdf[pages=-,fitpaper=true,noautoscale,width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{presentation.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Instead of 11:8.5 inches, you can choose whatever you wish.
You just have to make sure that the ratio fits.
The pdfpages package offers other options too that might enable a switch of format.

Kind regards
Florian

Comment: You could avoid the hazel with an extra document by using the `pgfpages` instead to resize the pages

Comment: (be aware that such resizing might cause problems with cross-references, included multimedia content, slide transition etc.)

Comment: With current versions of beamer, you no longer need `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}`

Comment: it works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `blowup` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{blowup}
\blowUp{target=a4,landscape}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
    \lipsum[1-5] 
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting solution (+1), however, I have problem how to insert text in frame. The text in the example `\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
   \lipsum[1-5]
\end{frame}
`  is wide only about 1/3 of frame width. Rest of page is not accessible.

Comment: @Zarko Can't reproduce. For me line breaks are the same as for normal beamer

Comment: hm, in test I use `beamer` v3.67 and  `blowup`  1 (from 2018/01/02) using recent MiKTeX on W10 machine.

Comment: @Zarko `blowup 2022/09/19 2.0.0` here

Comment: (and beamer v3.68, but I don't think we changed anything related to this...)

Comment: AH, how to convince MiKTeX to load recent `blowup`? MiKTeX Console say that blowup is from 7.1.2018 packaged 22.9.20022. It seems that I need to wait a while for the next MiKTeX update ...

Comment: @Zarko The easiest way to get current packages with miktex is to uninstall it and install texlive instead. Much better tested , more stable, picks up updates within a day and avoids all these headaches with the different modes.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I'm affray that I'm a bit to old for such a changes. But when I will replace my old (with the first Intel 7 generation :-( ) PC wit some recent machine (hopefully soon), I will try your suggestion ...

Comment: Today MiKTeX update (among others) `beamer` and `blowup` packages. Now your example wok in my LaTeX installation too.