# beamerposter and footnotes: an empty page is inserted

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

I already asked this on
https://github.com/deselaers/latex-beamerposter/issues
but the project seems a bit deserted. Be it as it may, please consider

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a4,scale=4]{beamerposter} % e.g. for DIN-A4 poster best for iPad writing
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label={sec:orgcfcdac7}]{This is a test of footnotes}
Consider\footnote{in the literal sense}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

when compiled it always inserts an empty page before the frame page.
Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?
thanks and regards

Uwe Brauer

Comment: seems to be a long standing bug https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191614/2388

Comment: It seems a workaround has been posted here
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191614/adding-a-frame-footnote-in-beamerposter-creates-blank-page-at-beginning

Comment: as I wrote. But I wouldn't use a package with such a bug. Use tcolorbox for posters.

Comment: Well, I have already more than 100 slides in beamer, but it turned out when importing the PDF to my iPad in all note taking apps, the pens I used got extremely thick, the authorsof these apps explained that the  culprit was beamer since it was not A4 format. So beamerposter solved this problem, I can now import all the pdfs without a problem, without transforming beamer frames into tcolorboxes. The price of using beamerposter  is this bug, for which a workaround exists

Comment: @UweBrauer If it is just for the papersize, have a look at pgfpages. This allows you to rescale the slides to A4 without changing the layout of the frames.

Comment: @samcarter, thanks I also found your proposal
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55342/is-there-a-way-to-change-papersize-in-beamer but blowup does not work in my TeXlive2019

Comment: @UweBrauer True it needs TL2022. However from your description, I don't think you should look into changing the page geometry. Leave the page geometry as it is and use pgfpages to scale the pages up to A4

Comment: Ok I just tried that, if I understand that correctly the logic is:
I first compile the beamer.tex
and then I recompile the beamer.pdf in a different file
That sounds  a bit cumbersome, but I give it a try.and see how it fits into my workflow